# Embed datafile in java code

Tags: java, serialization, stanford-nlp, text-analysis, bytestream

I have a dictionary file that is being used for word matching, the java code is to be submitted online and get executed.(for a online coding competition)
How would I be able to use the dictionary data file, while my program executes online.
could it be embedded in the source code as compressed byte stream?
please suggest

Comment: Can you not upload the program with the datafile included, e.g. in a resource folder?

Comment: no i cant as they have provided only space to upload the java code.Main idea is to train a model on some data file(they have provided corpus data)( i used dictionary text file instead), and the model developed would be used to correct the spelling of a word(passed as test case).

Comment: Sorry, so you're only allowed to upload .java source files? Or compiled .class files?

Comment: yes i am allowed to upload .java source file only.

Comment: In that case I think your options are to either host the dictionary online somewhere and get your program to pull from there, or to simply store the data as a static map/array/whatever in a separate source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this:

- either refer to the dictionairy file as a remote resource in your code.  This means that you ll most your dictionary file on a different online location which is well known by your online application code.  You can then download the dictionary file and cache the file in memory for usage
- You can encode the dictionary file (for instance in Base64 encoding - to take care of special characters in the dictonary file) as a predefined datastructure / buffer in your code.  This means however that you need to convert your dictionary file & rebuild your application each time you adapt the dictionary file.

Pointing to a different "online" location would seem to more suitable solution.

Comment: Not sure if the program executes offline, if thats the case i wont be able to access the file at online location.( But i may wanna try this)
Talking of other option the file is 3.2 MB, so might need some compression.Dont know how to acheive that.:(

Comment: Thanks Filip, Luckily the dictionary i used had direct link and could be accessed from the online editor.So i can proceed.